# Rectangle - Emgu CV

Tags: emgucv, rectangles

I'm trying to distinguish circular and rectangular objects from an image. I've labeled the round ones, using contours and the formula:

```
metric = 4*pie*contour.Area / (contour.perimeter^2)
```

Since I'm almost done, I wanted to know the alternate of this formula, which works for Rectangles. I'm bit weak in mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple tutorial from Emgu cv on finding shapes in an image.
It lets you find circles, triangles and squares.
You can check it out here [shape tutorial](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Shape_%28Triangle,_Rectangle,_Circle,_Line%29_Detection_in_CSharp).

Hope this helps you with your problem.